# show alert on empty select boxes without using ids or classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this JS Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type=select]').each(function() {
        if ($(this).text() == "") {
            alert("empty");
         }
    });
});
```

i want to show an alert box for each select box on my webpage but without using ids or classes

here is a fiddle of what i tried: http://jsfiddle.net/Kb9da/

Answer (score 0):

Here is my jquery solution :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('select').change(function() {
        if ($(this).find("option:selected").text() == "Empty Option") {
            alert("empty");
        }
    });
});
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Kb9da/2/)**

Hope this will solve the problem.

Regards,

Comment: Do is work on page load? or you have to select an empty to alert

Comment: @Tasos : Nope! Whether user3815283 expecting that?

Comment: I dont know. user3815283 put a comment on my answer "and not on change either, just on page load - if the option value is blank it will do something"

Comment: @Tasos: You are right! User was mentioned in one of comments... Better to Update post! Still quetion is not clear :-(

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event/handler

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('select').on('change', function () {
       if ($(this).find(":selected").text() == "Empty Option") {
            alert("empty");
         }
    });
});
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Kb9da/8/)**

You could also use `.val()` by setting the value attributes on each `<option>`.

Since you have a `value=""` for the first `option`...This should also work:

```
if ($(this).find(":selected").val() == "") {
// code here
}
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Kb9da/9/)**

If you just want the alert to show on page load, use:

```
$('select').each(function () {
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo don't need to use `.each` loop to achieve this. You can handle it by using `change` event:

```
$('select').on("change",
 function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "") {
        alert("empty");
     }
});
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Kb9da/7/)

Also `select` is **not** input.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below jquery code to validate all the select boxes. I have used the change event.

JS

```
$('select').change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "") {
        alert(" empty "+ ($('select').index($(this))+1 ));
     }
});
```

[DEMO link with multiple selectbox](http://jsfiddle.net/Kb9da/12/)